# Firefox Start page stay white

Tags: firefox, boot, homepage

I'm a Firefox user since several years so I know it but today I had a strange problem. I installed the last stable version of Firefox (3.5.5) on a computer but when I launch the browser the page stay empty (blank).

In the settings I set the startpage as Google but nothing to do. When the browser starts in the address bar it is well written google.com but the page remains blank. I must click on the button in the address bar so that the site appears.

I've never had this problem with Firefox, it's strange. Thanks

Comment: the last stable version of Firefox would be 3.5.6 ... 3.5.5 was replaced VERY soon after its official release.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running 64-bit windows 7?  I had the same problem on Google Chrome with an early build of Windows 7 64-Bit.